# How to use AND and OR when using Algolia's numerical filter

Tags: algolia

Consider an Algolia index filled with objects like this:

```
{ 
   "objectID": 1, 
   "name": "My project title", 
   "contributor_ids": [12, 42, 34] 
}
```

Does this query get all objects that have contributor_ids 42 OR contributor_ids=12 ?

```
"numericFilters: 'contributor_ids=42, contributor_ids=12"
```

And if so, what is the right query to  get all objects that have contributor_ids 42 AND contributor_ids=12 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior is a AND, you can have a OR with parenthesis:

```
numericFilters: "contributor_ids=42, contributor_ids=12"
```

Means contributor_ids=42 AND contributor_ids=12, only match if you have a record containing both values

```
numericFilters: "(contributor_ids=42, contributor_ids=12)"
```

Means contributor_ids=42 OR contributor_ids=12

```
numericFilters: "contributor_ids=10,(contributor_ids=42, contributor_ids=12)"
```

Means contributor_ids=10 AND (contributor_ids=42 OR contributor_ids=12)

Comment: Thank you for this.  Now I know why my search was returning the wrong data.